# Polymorphic relationship when model already belongs to one of the models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-modeling

I've got `Area`s and `ClickMap`s. An `Area` has many `ClickMap`s and a `ClickMap` belongs to an area. Simple.

The problem is each `ClickMap` also has one target, but a target needs to be polymorphic as the target can be one of a number of models, including an `Area`. But this is obviously a problem as an `Area` has many `ClickMap`s twice...

Here's what I've currently got:

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :click_maps, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :click_maps, as: :targetable
end

class ClickMap < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :area
  belongs_to :targetable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Any help appreciated. I may well just have the stoopids at the moment...

Perhaps I need in interstitial `Target` model?

**UPDATE**

I ended up just removing the `has_many :click_maps, as: :targetable` line. That was pointless. I just need to be able to call `click_map.targetable` and get back the correct object.

Comment: Why do you need the direct relationship if you have the polymorphic one?

Comment: @DVG yea now that I'm thinking of it I'm pretty sure what I need to do is add `Target` model, because an `Area` should actually belong to one `Target`, while also having many `ClickMap`s.

Comment: @DVG yea nevermind. See update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After including the `polymorphic association`, I don't think you still need direct `has_many` association between `Area` and `ClickMap` model.